# MERN - Getting error: "Cannot read property 'path' of undefined" when trying to upload a pdf file using multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, model-view-controller, react-redux, multer

Like I said on the title, I'm facing that error when I'm trying to upload a file from the client-side. Here are the code blocks for more context:

Route:

```
const express = require("express");
const { upload } = require("../middlewares/uploadMiddleware");

const { registerResearchSheet } = require("../controllers/researchSheetControllers");

const router = express.Router();
router.route("/").post(upload.single("file"), registerResearchSheet);
```

Middleware:

```
const multer = require("multer");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "backend/uploads/");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(
      null,
      new Date().toISOString().replace(/:/g, "-") + "-" + file.originalname
    );
  },
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (file.mimetype === "application/pdf") {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
};

const upload = multer({ storage: storage, fileFilter: fileFilter });

module.exports = { upload };
```

Controller:

```
const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");
const ResearchSheet = require("../models/researchSheetModel");

const registerResearchSheet = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
  const {
    title,
    director,
    coordinator,
    students,
    reviewers,
    proposalType,
    investigationType,
    status,
  } = req.body;

  if (!req.file) {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error("The file hasn't be uploaded correctly"); **//This is the triggering error**
  }
  const file = req.file.path;

  const researchSheetExists = await ResearchSheet.findOne({ title, students });
  if (researchSheetExists) {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error("Title or students can't be repeated");
  }

  const researchSheet = await ResearchSheet.create({
    title,
    file, // file: buffer,
    director,
    coordinator,
    students,
    reviewers,
    proposalType,
    investigationType,
    status,
  });

  if (researchSheet) {
    res.status(201).json({
      _id: researchSheet._id,
      title: researchSheet.title,
      file: researchSheet.file,
      director: researchSheet.director,
      coordinator: researchSheet.coordinator,
      students: researchSheet.students,
      reviewers: researchSheet.reviewers,
      proposalType: researchSheet.proposalType,
      investigationType: researchSheet.investigationType,
      status: researchSheet.status,
    });
  } else {
    res.status(400);
    throw new Error("An error has ocurred");
  }
});
```

And finally the frontend part:

```
const [file, setFile] = useState(null);

//code..

const singleFileUpload = (e) => {
    setFile(e.target.files[0]);
  };

  const submitHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("title", title);
    formData.append("file", file);
    formData.append("director", director);
    formData.append("coordinator", coordinator);
    formData.append("students", students);
    formData.append("proposalType", proposalType);
    formData.append("investigationType", investigationType);

    console.log(file); //This log is correctly showing the File and its properties

    if (
      !title ||
      !coordinator ||
      !students ||
      !proposalType ||
      !investigationType
    ) {
      setMessage("You must fill all the fields");
    } else {
      dispatch(registerResearchSheetAction(formData));
      // history.push("/listresearchsheets");
    }
  };

//more code...

<Form.Control
          className="mb-3"
          type="file"
          accept=".pdf"
          onChange={(e) => singleFileUpload(e)}
        />
        <Button type="submit">Register</Button>
```

Action:

```
export const registerResearchSheetAction =
  (
    title,
    file,
    director,
    coordinator,
    students,
    reviewers,
    proposalType,
    investigationType,
    status
  ) =>
  async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      dispatch({
        type: RESEARCHSHEET_REGISTER_REQUEST,
      });

      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("file", file);
      formData.append("title", title);
      formData.append("director", director);
      formData.append("coordinator", coordinator);
      formData.append("students", students);
      formData.append("reviewers", reviewers);
      formData.append("proposalType", proposalType);
      formData.append("investigationType", investigationType);
      formData.append("status", status);

      const config = {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      };

      const { data } = await axios.post(
        "/api/researchsheets",
        formData,
        config
      );

      dispatch({ type: RESEARCHSHEET_REGISTER_SUCCESS, payload: data });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: RESEARCHSHEET_REGISTER_FAIL,
        payload:
          error.response && error.response.data.message
            ? error.response.data.message
            : error.message,
      });
    }
  };
```

I already tested the functionality on the server-side using Postman and it is uploading, more than the file, the route/path of it successfully on the database. That's why I'm thinking that the problem must be on the client-side. I really don't know what I'm missing here, so that's why I came for a little of help, I hope I was clear on my explanaiton.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How are you submitting the form? Verify that the incoming request has a body on the server.

Comment: So sorry, forgot to add the action code since I'm using redux too. Let me edit the post in order to give more context about the problem.

Comment: So on the server `req.file` does exist, correct?

Comment: How can I be sure of that? I assuming that it does exist because there's no problem on the server but I really don't know tbh.

Comment: Oh, sorry, when you submit to the server does it error (execute the throw if `req.file` doesn't exist)?

Comment: Yeah it is like when I submit the form on the front-end it does giving me the error, so I'm guessing that is taking in count that `req.file` doesn't exist, but when I try to submit it by Postman it works normally, all the data goes to mongodb without any problem. Sorry if I'm misunderstanding your responses, I hope I was clear on this one.

Comment: Okay, so we can conclude that you're sending the frontend data incorrectly. Double check that.

Comment: Exactly, but the thing is that I'm not shure what I'm doing wrong there. As I've understood from the research that I've been doing, its because of the `multipart/form-data`, but I have it already on the headers, so idk what else can be happening.